# LiDAR coverage East Africa

Tags: research

I want to use ArcGIS to pinpoint the location of fossils.
There are three variables related to the fossils: (i) lat/long; (ii) elevation.

All of the fossils are hominin fossils found in East Africa.

I would like to know if LiDAR exists for East Africa (Kenya / Turkana) regions? If not, is it possible to do this project without LiDAR?

The reason I want to use LiDAR is to get a more in-depth view of the landscape to examine fluvial landforms such as rivers, terraces, and lakes - but maybe it is still possible to do this in ArcGIS Pro without LiDAR?

Comment: How far did you go with this? We have LiDAR here in Uganda